# Identifying a block of unicode using regular expressions

Tags: regex, stata

I have a list of paths corresponding to `xlsx` files that I want to import into Stata:

```
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                                                               path |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |                              G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data\house.dta |
  2. |                        G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data\import_data.log |
  3. |                G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨\哈尔滨_house.txt  |
  4. |                 G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨\哈尔滨_land.txt  |
  5. |             G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\0_银泰城.xlsx  |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |      G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1000_芦家街住宅.xlsx  |
  7. |        G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1001_国泰小区.xlsx  |
  8. | G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1002_花园街193号小区.xlsx  |
  9. |        G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1003_中发郦苑.xlsx  |
 10. |        G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1004_荣耀宝座.xlsx  |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Moreover, each path contains an uncertain Unicode expression (Chinese characters), which is actually a city name (the **first block of** Unicodes, such as "`哈尔滨`" in this case).

I would like to extract this Unicode string using a function like `regexr`.

How can I write the code？

Answer (score 2):

Use this patter to match Chinese characters:

```
[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+
```

Only take the first match if there is one. [Please check out this demo](http://regexr.com/3ct6v)

Comment: I try this command `replace city = regexs(0) if regexm(dirname, "^[\]+[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+")` or `replace city = regexs(0) if regexm(dirname, "[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+")` in stata, but it does not capture the unicode.

Comment: @zlqs1985: I see Stata starts Unicode support from version 14. What's your version? Try this pattern `([^\x00-\x7F]+)` if you are using a version below 14. [This is the demo](http://regexr.com/3ct6v).

Comment: @zlqs1985: Also you could try [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/kE2pX8/1) to find the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
[^\w^\:\\\/]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/bC2oR0/1

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Stata's otherwise excellent FAQs have not quite caught up with the new Unicode versions of the regular expression functions that were introduced in version 14. These are based on the ICU regular expression engine. The older `regexr()` ones you mentioned are just for plain ASCII, as is stated in the help file (see `help f_regexm`). You can learn more about the differences between the two sets of functions [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1327564-new-program-for-regular-expressions/page2).

If I understand your question, I want something like:

```
gen city_name = ustrregexs(0) if ustrregexm(path,"[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+")==1
```

Working from the end, the if-statement at the end will limit to paths where you have one or more relevant Unicode characters and the 0 in `ustrregexs(0)` tells Stata to return the entire string that satisfies the regular expression in previous `ustrregexm()` match.

Answer (score 0):

If the path structure for the `xlsx` files is always the same, you could alternatively use a combination of the `substr()`, `strpos()` and `strrpos()` functions:

```
clear

input strL string
"G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\0_银泰城.xlsx"
"G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1000_芦家街住宅.xlsx"
"G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1001_国泰小区.xlsx"
"G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1002_花园街193号小区.xlsx"
"G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1003_中发郦苑.xlsx"
"G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1004_荣耀宝座.xlsx"
end

generate new_string = substr(string, strpos(string, "/") + 1, abs(strpos(string, "/") - ///
                      strrpos(string, "/")) - 1)

list

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                                                             string   new_st~g |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |             G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\0_银泰城.xlsx       哈尔滨 |
  2. |      G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1000_芦家街住宅.xlsx       哈尔滨 |
  3. |        G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1001_国泰小区.xlsx       哈尔滨 |
  4. | G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1002_花园街193号小区.xlsx       哈尔滨 |
  5. |        G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1003_中发郦苑.xlsx       哈尔滨 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |        G:\Data_backup\Soufang_data/哈尔滨/house\1004_荣耀宝座.xlsx       哈尔滨 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```